# Angularjs : fitlering json properties to be send in a request

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Is there anyway to tell angularjs ( $http service) not to send some properties into a Json object when doing a HTTP POST?

Let's say that i have an Object definition like this :

```
 $scope.toBeSaved = { id : 1,
   name: myname,
   someAttributeTobeFiltered : 1233459,   
 }
```

Is There anyway to filter the `someAttributeTobeFiltered` not to be send during a `$http.post(url,$scope.toBeSaved)` call?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just filter the object before you pass it to $http. You can use an angular filter function or write it yourself

Comment: you could you method like _.omit - https://lodash.com/docs#omit to remove properties from object;

Comment: could you develop how the filter function would do it?

Comment: Are we talking about one time in one post? Then just clean it up yourself before you post it. If you want to do it universally, on all posts, then you can create a global interceptor https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Comment: @shershen could i use _.omit with multiple properties?

Comment: @DylanWatt in multiple place

Comment: @MasterMind, yes! as documentation says "... or arrays of property names."

Comment: If you're saving a collection, the array map function works pretty well for transforming your objects if you have a lot of keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the given property on every request made via $http.

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider )
{
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data)
    {
        if(typeof data === "object")
        {
            var toSend = angular.copy(data);
            delete toSend.someAttributeTobeFiltered;
            return toSend;

        }
        else{
            return data;
        }
    }];

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

So using _.omit method you can do following:

```
$http.post(url, _.omit($scope.toBeSaved, ['someAttributeTobeFiltered', 'foo', 'bar']))
```

Comment: Seems excessive to pull in a library just for this?

Comment: @Shershen good answer but i have to choose one answer i owe you an accepted answer for next time